# Framer-motion ease entire animation with keyframes

Tags: reactjs, jsx, framer-motion

I have an animation where an SVG image starts at `pathLength: 0` and `strokeOpacity: 0` and then takes 0.5s to fade the strokeOpacity to 1 and takes 4s for pathLength to go to 1 and then waits a sec then reverses, BUT, I want the strokeOpacity to go back to 0 when the pathLenght is nearly 0. It's working right now but the easing is very odd, it eases in between each keyframe and not the entire animation, so it goes fast then slow then fast then slow

Here's the code:

```
<svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <motion.path
                        className={styles.svgAnimation}
                        animate={{
                            strokeOpacity: [0, 1, 1, 1],
                            pathLength: [0, 1/3, 2/3, 1],
                        }}
                        transition={{
                            default: {
                                duration: 2,
                                ease: 'easeInOut',
                                delay: 1.5,
                                repeat: Infinity,
                                repeatType: 'reverse',
                                repeatDelay: 1,
                                times: [0, 1/3, 2/3, 1],
                            },
                            fill: { duration: 1,
                                    ease: 'easeIn',
                                    delay: 4.5,
                                    repeat: Infinity,
                                    repeatType: 'reverse',
                                    repeatDelay: 1},
                        }}
                        strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"
                        d="M7.5 8.25h9m-9 3H12m-9.75 1.51c0 1.6 1.123 2.994 2.707
                        3.227 1.129.166 2.27.293 3.423.379.35.026.67.21.865.501L12
                        21l2.755-4.133a1.14 1.14 0 0 1 .865-.501 48.172 48.172 0 0 0
                        3.423-.379c1.584-.233 2.707-1.626
                        2.707-3.228V6.741c0-1.602-1.123-2.995-2.707-3.228A48.394
                        48.394 0 0 0 12 3c-2.392 0-4.744.175-7.043.513C3.373 3.746
                        2.25 5.14 2.25 6.741v6.018Z" />
                    </svg>
```

I've tried making the easing into like `easings: [(array of easings)]` but that didn't work